# bind9: reverse resolution not working

Tags: bind

My forward resolution works and the reverse resolution fails, unable to figure out the problem. I appreciate if someone point the configuration error. Here you go for some files and output

```
dinesh@ubuntu:~$ sudo named-checkzone 168.192.in-addr.arpa /etc/bind/zones/db.192.168 
zone 168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 4
OK
```

**/etc/zones/db.192.168**

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ns1.lab.co.in admin.lab.co.in. (
                  3     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;

; name servers
      IN      NS      ns1.lab.co.in.
      IN      NS      ns2.lab.co.in.

; PTR Records
7.1    IN      PTR     ns1.lab.co.in.    ; 192.168.7.1
7.110   IN      PTR     ns2.lab.co.in.    ; 192.168.7.110
1.1 IN      PTR     r1.lab.co.in.  ; 1.1.1.1
2.2     IN      PTR     r2.lab.co.in.  ; 2.2.2.2
3.3 IN      PTR     r3.lab.co.in.  ; 3.3.3.3
4.4 IN      PTR     r4.lab.co.in.  ; 4.4.4.4
5.5 IN      PTR     r5.lab.co.in.  ; 5.5.5.5
6.6 IN      PTR     r6.lab.co.in.  ; 6.6.6.6
7.7 IN      PTR     r7.lab.co.in.  ; 7.7.7.7
8.8 IN      PTR     r8.lab.co.in.  ; 8.8.8.8
9.9 IN      PTR     r9.lab.co.in.  ; 9.9.9.9
10.10   IN      PTR     r10.lab.co.in.  ; 10.10.10.10
```

Comment: Please add the contents of your `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` file to your question.

Comment: I guess your `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` file is on [another of your questions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/885855/bind9-does-not-respond-to-queries-from-hosts). You need to define one sub-net and stick to it. Currently you are defining stuff all over the place in terms of IP addresses.

Comment: It is fixed now.. here the thread goes...  http://serverfault.com/questions/835112/bind9-reverse-resolution-not-working